# When I deploy on WebSphere 8.5.5 using Eclipse, the application doesn't start: ADMA0511E

Tags: eclipse, websphere

I am using Eclipse Luna, WAS 8.5.5 on Red Hat 7. I've installed WAS Tools (Was Adapter).

My problem is the Eclipse install the application on WebSphere, but can't start it. Eclipse shows message: ADMA0511E: There is no module target specified for the application.

How can I set the target for my application modules?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the web or whatever module to the EAR's `applications.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
    <display-name>macc-ear</display-name>
    <module id="Module_1381754217072">
        <web>
            <web-uri>macc-frontend.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/macc</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure all modules in the application mapped to the servers. You can check the mapping in the deployment.xml file or use the console, click on enterprise application -> application name ->manage module and make sure its mapped.